# Firebase Android: Google Sign In Failure

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

First of all, I have to say I'm very very new to Android development so forgive me if I overlook something obvious.

For a university project, I have to create an app that first authenticates users via their Google Account using Firebase. I first followed the instructions I found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin).

For a start, I copy pasted [this code from Firebase Tutorial.](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java) Everything seems to be working, except for one thing :

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.d(TAG, "------------------ onActivityResult ------------------");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "------------------ googleSignInSuccess ------------------");
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            // Start menu activity once the user has been logged in
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "------------------ googleSignInFailure ------------------");
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            //Log.d(TAG, result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
            updateUI(null);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `result.isSuccess() == false`. So I think the Google authentication fails for some reason I cannot understand. I am sure I entered the right password, I also enabled Google Account authentication in my app's Firebase Console.

Thank you very much in advance if you can help me.

**EDIT** : To be more precise, the first time I run the program on my emulator (or after each time I wipe data from it), I have to enter my Google credentials in the dedicated Google login activity that pops up. This works fine and the same activity seems to successfully authenticate me. However after that, `result.isSuccess()` is still false and I don't understand why.

Comment: Would be helpful to analyse the problem if you can provide the other part of the code

Comment: Which part do you mean ?

Comment: How you are making the client request

Comment: i had the same problem, i had not given the SHA certs for the app, it's a vital step you can do it like this. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally found the problem, I made a mistake while authenticating my app in the Firebase Console [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin)  (section "before you begin"), 4th step. I entered the `debug` one instead and it works now.

Thanks nonetheless!

Answer (score 2):

You can check status of the result with `result.getStatus().getStatusMessage()`. Log this message or debug your result [Status](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/Status.html) and it should indicate issue. `Status` has also `getResolution()` method that provides pending intent that should resolve your failure (firstly check if resolution is available with calling `hasResolution()`, which returns `true` if it can handle it for you).

Comment: I tried your solution and I am able to get the status message, however printing it in the IDE's terminal using Log.d (the only way that I know of so far) crashes my app. Furthermore, the hasResolution() method returns false.

Comment: Where do you get this `result`? All I get back from onActivityResults are INTs onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?)

Comment: check the data: Intent?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing GSO by :

```java
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

Hope this helps !